# If modified on same day, show only time

Tags: posts, comments, date, date-time, wp-update-post

I have a date on each post and comment which shows the date of placement.

If I edit it, it shows me the date of the post and the modified date. That's fine, but now, I want to show only the post date AND the TIME of the modified date only if the post is edited on the same day as it's posted.

So for example:

```
If a post is has been submitted on 8 march 2013 15:00, show me: 08-03-2013 15:00
If a post is edited on 8 march 2013 16:30, show me: 08-03-2013 15:00 - 16:30
If a post is edited on 9 march 2013 17:00, show me: 08-03-2013 15:00 - 09-03-2013 17:00
```

How can I do this? I am using something like this, except for the AM and PM.

```
<?php the_modified_date('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_modified_date('g:i a'); ?>
```

How can I only show the time if it's modified on the same date?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
if(get_the_modified_date('zY')==date('zY')) {  
the_modified_date('g:i a'); 
} else {
the_modified_date('F j, Y'); echo ' at '; the_modified_date('g:i a');
}
```

It checks that the modified date is the current day. If it is, it only displays the modified time. Otherwise it displays both the date and time.

Comment: Hi Alex, how can I add that in this one? It is already in a if statement. How do I do that?

`<div class="info"><a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark">#'.get_the_ID().'</a> <time datetime='. get_the_date('d-m-Y') . '>%3$s '.get_the_time( $d, $post ).'</time>`